# anyway to quit smoothly looper.loop inside a run()?

Tags: android

I want to execute some code on like each 10 seconds (example only), and for this purpose I am using `TimerTask`.The problem is that within the `run()` method of `TimerTask` class, I am implementing `looper.prepare` and `looper.loop` , due to some handlers involved.The `looper.loop` seems to not return after first execution and therefore my TimerTask starts executes once and that is it. I tried using `looper.quit()`, but that didnt help either.Is there any nice way of making it work?

A small example :

```
public class Timez extends TimerTask {
    public void run () {      
        Looper.prepare();
        // some code here 
        Looper.loop();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To me, it sounds like you're using concepts which do not match your needs. The Looper.loop() is not a single step thing; it will loop until you quit the looper. So it's the opposite of a one-shot solution every 10 seconds. Maybe you want to describe your use case better.

Comment: ok i want to use the requestlocationupdates inside the run () , and because it uses internal handler it requires a looper, is that task conceptually possible to do it that way ?

Comment: What is the reason you want your task to run only every 10 seconds? The location updates will come whenever necessary, and you'll have to process them.